# Kubernetes Affinity Prevent Jenkins Workers From Running On Main

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Jenkins is running on EKS and there are affinity rules in place on both the Jenkins main and worker pods.

The idea is to prevent the Jenkins worker pods from running on the same EKS worker nodes, where the Jenkins main pod is running.

The following rules work, until resources limits are pushed, at which point the Jenkins worker pods are scheduled onto the same EKS worker nodes as the Jenkins master pod.

Are there affinity / anti-affinity rules to prevent this from happening?

The rules in place for Jenkins main:

```
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions: # assign to eks apps worker group
            - key: node.app/group
              operator: In
              values:
                - apps
  podAntiAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions: # don't assign to a node running jenkins main
          - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
            operator: In
            values:
              - jenkins
          - key: app.kubernetes.io/component
            operator: In
            values:
              - main
        topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
    preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 100
        podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions: # try not to assign to a node already running a jenkins worker
              - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
                operator: In
                values:
                  - jenkins
              - key: app.kubernetes.io/component
                operator: In
                values:
                  - worker
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

The rules in place for Jenkins worker:

```
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions: # assign to eks apps worker group
          - key:  node.app/group
            operator: In
            values:
              - apps
  podAntiAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions: # don't assign to a node running jenkins main
          - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
            operator: In
            values:
              - jenkins
          - key: app.kubernetes.io/component
            operator: In
            values:
              - main
        topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
    preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 100
        podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions: # try not to assign to a node already running a jenkins worker
              - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
                operator: In
                values:
                  - jenkins
              - key: app.kubernetes.io/component
                operator: In
                values:
                  - worker
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

Answer (score 1):

So low and behold guess what...the main pod labels weren't set correctly.

Now you can see the selector lables displaying here:

```
> aws-vault exec nonlive-build -- kubectl get po -n cicd --show-labels
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    LABELS
jenkins-6597db4979-khxls              2/2     Running   0          4m8s   app.kubernetes.io/component=main,app.kubernetes.io/instance=jenkins
```

To achieve this, new entries were added to the values file:

```
main:
  metadata:
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: jenkins
      app.kubernetes.io/component: main
```

And the Helm _helpers.tpl template was updated accordingly:

```
{{- define "jenkins.selectorLabels" -}}
app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
{{- if .Values.main.metadata.labels }}
{{- range $k, $v := .Values.main.metadata.labels }}
{{ $k }}: {{ $v }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```